# Google Charts Legend Position Not Working

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

This is driving me nuts. I can't get the legend to move at all. This produces a chart with the legend in it's default location on the right.

I clearly have legend position declared as "bottom" but it's not working. Yet this is exactly what the docs say.

```js
google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff(){
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
data.addColumn('number', 'Variance');
data.addRows([
  ['Smith',  35,  {v: -.1126,   f: '-11.26%'} ],
  ['Chalk',  53,  {v: -.0126,   f: '-1.26%'}  ],
  ['Hank',  84,  {v: -.0252,   f: '-2.52%'}  ],
  ['Jordan', 46,  {v: .0688,    f: '6.88%'}   ],
  ['Bernie', 1,   {v: 0,        f: '-'}       ],
  ['Ralph',  105, {v: -.0548,   f: '-5.48%'}  ]
]);

var options = {
  series: {
    0: {axis: 'Quotes'},
    1: {axis: 'Percent'}
  },
  axes: {
    y: {
      Quotes: {label: 'Subdmission Count'},
      Percent: {label: '% Percent'}
    }
  },
  legend: { 
    position : 'bottom'
  }
};

var table = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('table1'));

table.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='table1'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`legend.position: ['top', 'bottom']` -- are just a couple of the **many options that don't work** on *material charts*

see [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) for an extensive list

however, these options will work on a *core* chart...

*core* --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- using --> `packages: ['corechart']`

*material* --> `google.charts.Bar` -- using --> `packages: ['bar']`

there is also an option to get a *core* chart **close** to the look & feel of *material*

`theme: 'material'`

see following working snippet using *core* chart instead...

```js
google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff(){
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
data.addColumn('number', 'Variance');
data.addRows([
  ['Smith',  35,  {v: -.1126,   f: '-11.26%'} ],
  ['Chalk',  53,  {v: -.0126,   f: '-1.26%'}  ],
  ['Hank',  84,  {v: -.0252,   f: '-2.52%'}  ],
  ['Jordan', 46,  {v: .0688,    f: '6.88%'}   ],
  ['Bernie', 1,   {v: 0,        f: '-'}       ],
  ['Ralph',  105, {v: -.0548,   f: '-5.48%'}  ]
]);

var options = {
  chartArea: {
    height: '56%'
  },
  series: {
    1: {
      targetAxisIndex: 1
    }
  },
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Name'
  },
  vAxes: {
    0: {
      title: 'Submission Count'
    },
    1: {
      title: '% Percent'
    }
  },
  theme: 'material',
  legend: { 
    position : 'bottom'
  }
};

var table = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('table1'));

table.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='table1'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`{position: 'left'}` works fine in your example, so the only option left is that `'bottom'` this is not supported.

Similar discussion on guthub mentions that it is not supported for another chart type and not planned to be implemented: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1964